# Project created but its fields are empty when sent from React to Django API

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, web-deployment

I've been working on this React + Django APP. And I have been making a simple CRUD functionality into this app. everything goes fine but when i came to create project and send it to the django database, it gets created but when i look at it at `projects/list` it only shows the delete button and and image field which is not important, i only want the `title` and `body` fields to be shows
[image]

This is **views.py**

```
class CreateProjectView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        project = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
        if project.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            project.save()
            return Response(project.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
create_project = CreateProjectView.as_view({"get": "post"})
urlpatterns = [
   path("project/create", create_project, name="create-project"),
]
```

Now React `CreateProject.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const CreateProject = () => {

    let [project, setProject] = useState([])
    
    let [title, setProjectTitle] = useState("")
    let [body, setProjectBody] = useState("")
    
    const handleChangeTitle = (value) => {
        setProjectTitle(project => ({ ...title, 'title': value}))
        console.log("Title:", value)
    }
    
    const handleChangeBody = (value) => {
        setProjectBody(project => ({ ...body, 'body': value}))
        console.log("Body: ", value)
    }


    let createProject = async () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/project/create', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            },
            // title: JSON.stringify(project_title),
            // title: project_title,
            // body: project_body,
            // image: "hello",
            // title: title,
            // body: body
            project: {
                "title": title,
                "body": body
            }
            // project:  project.title
        },
        )
        // let project = {project_title, project_body}
    }
    
    let handleSubmit = () => {
        setProject(project)
        
        createProject()
    }

  return (
    <div>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <input type="text" name="title" onChange={e => {handleChangeTitle(e.target.value)}} defaultValue={project?.title} />
        <br />
        <h3>body</h3>
        <input type="text" name="body" onChange={e => {handleChangeBody(e.target.value)}} defaultValue={project?.body} />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        
        <button onClick={createProject}>submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateProject
```

**ProjectViewSet in view.py**

```
class ProjectView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

I was expecting it to show the `title` and `body` fields and they content that were created in the create project page

Comment: Please add the List View code from Django and also from react as well.

Comment: have you tried finding where the code is incorrect? Are you getting data in your api? can you put ```print("data>>", request.data)``` at the beginning of your post function, just before ```project = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)``` line?

Comment: @DivyaPrakash It doesn't tell me neither on the django API nor on the React console or the web's that there is an error, It just creates the project but with no data inside the fields, and it also get's sent to the api empty (`[
    {
        "id": 36,
        "image": null,
        "title": null,
        "body": null,
        "created": "2022-11-08T14:01:07.468274Z",
        "updated": "2022-11-08T14:01:07.468274Z"
    }
]`)
And when i added the print statements as you said it just returns this as output in the django console `data: {}`.

Comment: @FaisalNazik You mean the view that i got my data passed to react with? I included that now. Do you also want me to add the React component that accepts the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked. It turns out the problem in in the **CreateProject.js** components where the `createProject()` is.
so this is how i fixed it:
At first I was just sending the data fields like this:

```
title: project.title,
body: project.body,
```

but I should have been:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  title: project.title,
  body: project.body,
})
```

I tried removing the JSON.stringify and leaving it just a {} like this

```
body: {
  title: project.title,
}
```

but It has to be this way.
Anyways this is the correct way to send POST requests from React to Django uing React Functions

```
let updateProject = async () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/project/update/${projectId}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: project.title,
                body: project.body
            })
        })
    }
```